# Javascript problem: Works in FF but not in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

Hi this is my code which I use on one div in order to automatically set its height to window one. The script works great in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. I tried few methods to fix it including some from previous posters but without effect, unfortunatelly. I think that the problem is hiding somewhere in `document.getElementById("ID").style.height` but I am not completely sure. I will be glad if someone can help. Thanks in advance! :)

```
window.onload = Resize;
window.onresize = Resize;
function Resize() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight === document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  {
     document.getElementById("ID").style.height = (window.innerHeight-220) + "px";
  }
};
```

Comment: you have instructions here http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/u6x3t/)

```
function getHeight() {
    var myHeight = 0;
    if (typeof(window.innerHeight) == 'number') {
        //Non-IE
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body && document.body.clientHeight) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return myHeight;
}

function getScrollY() {
    var scrOfY = 0;
    if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
        //Netscape compliant
        scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    } else if (document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
        //DOM compliant
        scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
        //IE6 standards compliant mode
        scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return scrOfY;
}

function Resize() {
    document.getElementById("ID").style.height = Math.round(getHeight() + getScrollY()) + "px";
}
window.onload = Resize();
window.onresize = Resize();
```

This will set the height of the ID to the height of the browser window + the vertical scroll offset.

Comment: Tested in Chrome and FF, I don't have IE installed otherwise I would test on that as well... also no safari. Credit to @Senad Meškin as I used the instructions he provided to produce this.